# Testnet vs Livenet addresses

Tags: testnet, stellar-sdk

Whats the difference between testnet and livenet addresses ? 
Similar to bitcoin does stellar has different address scheme for testnet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Addresses are the same no matter what network you are on.

Transaction *hashes* are different, however.

(The transaction hash pre-image is formed by taking the network ID, and appending the transaction envelope XDR to it.)

Answer (score 2):

I think both live and test use same schema to generate addresses https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/Keypair.html